# MongoDB find documents before specific _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm creating some kind of real-chat app and I have trouble. What I want to do is read previous 50 messages(documents) before specified _id. I'll explain more detail.

In first time user getting in the room, App automatically load recent 50 messages. After, if user scrolling up to the top, load more 50 previous messages.

The problem is I don't get it how to do. What I thought is find all documents and move the cursor, but every I tried were failed. If I log the "cursor" object in console, it saids:

> Promise { <pending> }

so if I do this:

```
let cursor = db.find('room', { ... });

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    cursor.next();
}
```

it goes infinite loop, never stops. If will be very thanksful gimme a hand. :)
And if there is alternative way to not need to use cursor, that would be really nice.

- one more final question: is using cursor causes performance low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you use, it seems that `cursor` is an asynchronous object (that's what `Promise` suggests), so the while loop is incorrect anyway. It will always be pending cause you don't allow the other event (i.e. "i got response") to occure due to single-threaded nature of NodeJS. You probably have to use callbacks, not synchronous loops.

But that aside I do believe that your whole approach is incorrect.

If you know how to load the most **recent** 50 messages, then it means that you have to have some kind of logical ordering on the collection. Perhaps a timestamp (which might be a part of `id_`).

So what I propose instead is something similar to "pagination":

1. On the client side set `timestamp_pointer = now()`
2. Do a query: get me 50 most recent messages such that `timestamp < timestamp_pointer`
3. On the client side set `timestamp_pointer = smallest timestamp of loaded messages`
4. If a user scrolls up go back to point 2.

There are several advantages of this method, one of them is that you don't have to worry if a connection drops for a short moment since the state is tracked on the user side, not on the database side. And with a proper index it will be very fast.

And yes, using cursor like you do causes low performance because the database has to keep track of the query until it is fully iterated. Apart from pure memory and/or cpu usage it has some other nasty drawbacks, like Mongo has timeouts on cursors. What if a user scrolls up after 15 minutes? By default the timeout on cursor is 10 minutes. It would be very hard to implement your idea properly.

---

Use Postgres. #PostgresEvangelist

Comment: What's with the _"Use Postgres"_? Are signatures a thing now on SO?

Comment: @robertklep Who knows? I just like to be original. :P